# Why are there global offset tables and procedure linkage tables in statically linked executables?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

I've done a bunch of reading on dynamic linker relocations and position independent code including procedure linkage tables and global offset tables. I don't understand why a statically linked executable needs a PLT and GOT. I compiled a hello world program on my ubuntu x86_64 machine and when I dump the section headers with `readelf -S` it shows PLT and GOT sections.

I also created a shared library with a simple increment function that I compiled with `gcc -shared` without `-fpic` and I also see PLT and GOT sections. I didn't expect this either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why a statically linked executable needs a PLT and GOT.

It doesn't.

> I compiled a hello world program on my ubuntu x86_64 machine and when I dump the section headers with readelf -S it shows PLT and GOT sections.

This is an accident of implementation. The sections come from `crt1.o`, and there isn't a separate `crt1s.o` for fully-static linking, so you end up with `.plt` and `.got` entries from there.

You can strip these sections, and the binary will still work:

```
objcopy -R.got -R.plt a.out a.out2
```

Note: do not strip `.rela.plt`, as that section is still needed to implement `IFUNC`s.

Comment: There was also a `.got.plt` I was able to remove and the executable still ran. As you stated if I removed `.rela.plt` the executable segfaulted.

Answer (score 0):

I found that gcc generates a `.got` and `.got.lpt` when generating position independent code and taking the address of a function defined in another source file.

My test files were:

part1.c:

```
extern void afunc();

int _start()
{
  return 0x55 & (__SIZE_TYPE__) afunc;
}
```

part2.c:

```
void afunc() {}
```

My test was (substitute your own gcc version):

```
for o in s 4 3 2 1 0
do
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-10 -fPIC part1.c part2.c -o static.elf -static -nostdlib -O$o &&
  aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -x static.elf | grep 'GLOBAL_OFFSET'
done
```

I get the following output for all optimization levels:

```
0000000000410fd8 l     O .got   0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

Replacing `-fPIC` with `-fno-PIC` and the segment goes away.

You can tell if your compiler defaults to `-fPIC` by running this:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-10 -mcmodel=large -x c - < /dev/null
```

From which, I get the error, if it does:

```
cc1: sorry, unimplemented: code model ‘large’ with ‘-fPIC’
```