# Why does a fully static Rust ELF binary have a Global Offset Table (GOT) section?

Tags: rust, elf, got

This code, when compiled for the `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` target, produces a `.got` section:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

```
$ cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
$ readelf -S hello
There are 30 section headers, starting at offset 0x26dc08:

Section Headers:
[Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
   Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
...
[12] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000637b58  00037b58
   00000000000004a8  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
...
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34863068/3193180) for analogous C code, the `.got` section is an artifact that can be safely removed. However, it segfaults for me:

```
$ objcopy -R.got hello hello_no_got
$ ./hello_no_got
[1]    3131 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./hello_no_got
```

Looking at the disassembly, I see that the GOT basically holds static function addresses:

```
$ objdump -d hello -M intel
...
0000000000400340 <_ZN5hello4main17h5d434a6e08b2e3b8E>:
...
  40037c:       ff 15 26 7a 23 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x237a26]        # 637da8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x250>
...

$ objdump -s -j .got hello | grep 637da8
637da8 50434000 00000000 b0854000 00000000  PC@.......@.....

$ objdump -d hello -M intel | grep 404350
0000000000404350 <_ZN3std2io5stdio6_print17h522bda9f206d7fddE>:
  404350:       41 57                   push   r15
```

The number `404350` comes from `50434000 00000000`, which is a little-endian `0x00000000000404350` (this was not obvious; I had to run the binary under GDB to figure this out!)

This is perplexing, since Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Offset_Table) that

> [GOT] is used by executed programs to find during runtime addresses of global variables, unknown in compile time. The global offset table is updated in process bootstrap by the dynamic linker.

1. Why is the GOT present? From the disassembly, it looks like the compiler knows all the needed addresses. As far as I know, there is no bootstrap done by the dynamic linker: there is neither `INTERP` nor `DYNAMIC` program headers present in my binary;
2. Why does the GOT store function pointers? Wikipedia says the GOT is only for global variables, and function pointers should be contained in the PLT.

Comment: I don't know, but the first thing that comes to mind is that a lot of Rust's formatting machinery uses dynamic dispatch instead of static dispatch (for measured benefits). There's also the fact that you are using stdout, which is a global variable with a lock around it. I think the next step would be to rule out those two avenues.

Comment: are you sure you striped it correctly ? also, I'm not an expert but manipulate binary is not recommended. Every compiler has its own way to work.

Comment: @Stargateur If you mean `objcopy -R.got hello hello_no_got`, I am not an expert here (I just borrowed this command from the answer I gave a link to), but, as I mentioned after, `.got` section turns out to be an essential part of the binary. I know that manipulating the binary is not your usual way to go; for some reason (don't ask why) I want to embed a Rust binary in a Rust binary and run the inner binary from the outer one. So the first thing I did was to compile the inner binary with musl, which produces a fully static binary, but I was surprised to find GOT in it.

Comment: Actually the GOT is used for any _Position Independed Code_, not only dynamic libraries. I'm guessing that the Rust stdlib is compiled to PIC to be able to use it in shared libraries. So you get a GOT even if you don't technically need one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR summary**: the GOT is really a rudimentary build artifact, which I was able to get rid of via simple machine code manipulations.

## Breakdown

If we look at

```
$ objdump -dj .text hello
```

and search for `GLOBAL`, we see only four distinct types of references to the GOT (constants differ):

```
  40037c:       ff 15 26 7a 23 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x237a26]        # 637da8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x250>
  425903:       ff 25 5f 26 21 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x21265f]        # 637f68 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x410>
  41d8b5:       48 3b 1d b4 a5 21 00    cmp    rbx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x21a5b4]    # 637e70 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x318>
  40b259:       48 83 3d 7f cb 22 00    cmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x22cb7f],0x0    # 637de0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x288>
  40b260:       00
```

All of these are reading instructions, which means that the GOT is not modified at runtime. This in turn means that we can statically resolve the addresses that the GOT refers to! Let's consider the reference types one by one:

1. `call QWORD PTR [rip+0x2126be]` simply says "go to address `[rip+0x2126be]`, take 8 bytes from there, interpret them as a function address and call the function". We can simply replace this instruction with a direct call:

```
  40037c:       e8 cf 3f 00 00          call   404350 <_ZN3std2io5stdio6_print17h522bda9f206d7fddE>
  400381:       90                      nop
```

Notice the `nop` at the end: we need to replace all the 6 bytes of the machine code that constitute the first instruction, but the instruction we replace it with is only 5 bytes, so we need to pad it. Fundamentally, as we are patching a compiled binary, we can replace an instruction with a another one only if it is not longer.

2. `jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x21265f]` is the same as the previous one, but instead of calling an address it jumps to it. This turns into:

```
  425903:       e9 b8 f7 ff ff          jmp    4250c0 <_ZN68_$LT$core..fmt..builders..PadAdapter$u20$as$u20$core..fmt..Write$GT$9write_str17hc384e51187942069E>
  425908:       90                      nop
```

3. `cmp rbx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x21a5b4]` - this takes 8 bytes from `[rip+0x21a5b4]` and compares them to the contents of `rbx` register. This one is tricky, since `cmp` can not compare register contents to an 64-bit immediate value. We could use another register for that, but we don't know which of the registers are used around this instruction. A careful solution would be something like

```
push rax
mov rax,0x0000006363c0
cmp rbx,rax
pop rax
```

But that would be way beyond our limit of 7 bytes. The real solution stems from an observation that the GOT contains only addresses; our address space is (roughly) contained in range [0x400000; 0x650000], which can be seen in the program headers:

```
$ readelf -l hello
...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000035b50 0x0000000000035b50  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000036380 0x0000000000636380 0x0000000000636380
                 0x0000000000001dd0 0x0000000000003918  RW     0x200000
...
```

It follows that we can (mostly) get away with only comparing 4 bytes of a GOT entry instead of 8. So the substitution is:

```
  41d8b5:       81 fb c0 63 63 00       cmp    ebx,0x6363c0
  41d8bb:       90                      nop
```

4. The last one consists of two lines of `objdump` output, since 8 bytes do not fit in one line:

```
  40b259:       48 83 3d 7f cb 22 00    cmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x22cb7f],0x0    # 637de0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x288>
  40b260:       00
```

It just compares 8 bytes of the GOT to a constant (in this case, 0x0). In fact, we can do the comparison statically; if the operands compare equal, we replace the comparison with

```
  40b259:       48 39 c0                cmp    rax,rax
  40b25c:       90                      nop
  40b25d:       90                      nop
  40b25e:       90                      nop
  40b25f:       90                      nop
  40b260:       90                      nop
```

Obviously, a register is always equal to itself. A lot of padding needed here!

If the left operand is greater than the right one, we replace the comparison with

```
  40b259:       48 83 fc 00             cmp    rsp,0x0 
  40b25d:       90                      nop
  40b25e:       90                      nop
  40b25f:       90                      nop
  40b260:       90                      nop
```

In practice, `rsp` is always greater than zero.

If the left operand is smaller than the right one, things get a bit more complicated, but since we have a whole lot of bytes (8!) we can manage:

```
  40b259:  50                      push   rax
  40b25a:  31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  40b25c:  83 f8 01                cmp    eax,0x1
  40b25f:  58                      pop    rax
  40b260:  90                      nop
```

Notice that the second and the third instructions use `eax` instead of `rax`, since `cmp` and `xor` involving `eax` take one less byte than with `rax`.

## Testing

I have written a Python script to do all these substitutions automatically (it's a bit hacky and relies on parsing of `objdump` output though):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys
import argparse
import subprocess

def read_u64(binary):
    return sum(binary[i] * 256 ** i for i in range(8))

def distance_u32(start, end):
    assert abs(end - start) < 2 ** 31
    diff = end - start
    if diff < 0:
        return 2 ** 32 + diff
    else:
        return diff

def to_u32(x):
    assert 0 <= x < 2 ** 32
    return bytes((x // (256 ** i)) % 256 for i in range(4))

class GotInstruction:
    def __init__(self, lines, symbol_address, symbol_offset):
        self.address = int(lines[0].split(":")[0].strip(), 16)
        self.offset = symbol_offset + (self.address - symbol_address)
        self.got_offset = int(lines[0].split("(File Offset: ")[1].strip().strip(")"), 16)
        self.got_offset = self.got_offset % 0x200000  # No idea why the offset is actually wrong
        self.bytes = []
        for line in lines:
            self.bytes += [int(x, 16) for x in line.split("\t")[1].split()]

class TextDump:
    symbol_regex = re.compile(r"^([0-9,a-f]{16}) <(.*)> \(File Offset: 0x([0-9,a-f]*)\):")

    def __init__(self, binary_path):
        self.got_instructions = []
        objdump_output = subprocess.check_output(["objdump", "-Fdj", ".text", "-M", "intel",
                                                  binary_path])
        lines = objdump_output.decode("utf-8").split("\n")
        current_symbol_address = 0
        current_symbol_offset = 0
        for line_group in self.group_lines(lines):
            match = self.symbol_regex.match(line_group[0])
            if match is not None:
                current_symbol_address = int(match.group(1), 16)
                current_symbol_offset = int(match.group(3), 16)
            elif "_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_" in line_group[0]:
                instruction = GotInstruction(line_group, current_symbol_address,
                                             current_symbol_offset)
                self.got_instructions.append(instruction)

    @staticmethod
    def group_lines(lines):
        if not lines:
            return
        line_group = [lines[0]]
        for line in lines[1:]:
            if line.count("\t") == 1:  # this line continues the previous one
                line_group.append(line)
            else:
                yield line_group
                line_group = [line]
        yield line_group

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.got_instructions)

def read_binary_file(path):
    try:
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            return f.read()
    except (IOError, OSError) as exc:
        print(f"Failed to open {path}: {exc.strerror}")
        sys.exit(1)

def write_binary_file(path, content):
    try:
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(content)
    except (IOError, OSError) as exc:
        print(f"Failed to open {path}: {exc.strerror}")
        sys.exit(1)

def patch_got_reference(instruction, binary_content):
    got_data = read_u64(binary_content[instruction.got_offset:])
    code = instruction.bytes
    if code[0] == 0xff:
        assert len(code) == 6
        relative_address = distance_u32(instruction.address, got_data)
        if code[1] == 0x15:  # call QWORD PTR [rip+...]
            patch = b"\xe8" + to_u32(relative_address - 5) + b"\x90"
        elif code[1] == 0x25:  # jmp QWORD PTR [rip+...]
            patch = b"\xe9" + to_u32(relative_address - 5) + b"\x90"
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"unknown machine code: {code}")
    elif code[:3] == [0x48, 0x83, 0x3d]:  # cmp QWORD PTR [rip+...],<BYTE>
        assert len(code) == 8
        if got_data == code[7]:
            patch = b"\x48\x39\xc0" + b"\x90" * 5  # cmp rax,rax
        elif got_data > code[7]:
            patch = b"\x48\x83\xfc\x00" + b"\x90" * 3  # cmp rsp,0x0
        else:
            patch = b"\x50\x31\xc0\x83\xf8\x01\x90"  # push rax
                                                     # xor eax,eax
                                                     # cmp eax,0x1
                                                     # pop rax
    elif code[:3] == [0x48, 0x3b, 0x1d]:  # cmp rbx,QWORD PTR [rip+...]
        assert len(code) == 7
        patch = b"\x81\xfb" + to_u32(got_data) + b"\x90"  # cmp ebx,<DWORD>
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"unknown machine code: {code}")
    return dict(offset=instruction.offset, data=patch)

def make_got_patches(binary_path, binary_content):
    patches = []
    text_dump = TextDump(binary_path)
    for instruction in text_dump.got_instructions:
        patches.append(patch_got_reference(instruction, binary_content))
    return patches

def apply_patches(binary_content, patches):
    for patch in patches:
        offset = patch["offset"]
        data = patch["data"]
        binary_content = binary_content[:offset] + data + binary_content[offset + len(data):]
    return binary_content

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("binary_path", help="Path to ELF binary")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output file path", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    binary_content = read_binary_file(args.binary_path)
    patches = make_got_patches(args.binary_path, binary_content)
    patched_content = apply_patches(binary_content, patches)
    write_binary_file(args.output, patched_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now we can get rid of the GOT for real:

```
$ cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
$ ./resolve_got.py target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/hello -o hello_no_got
$ objcopy -R.got hello_no_got
$ readelf -e hello_no_got | grep .got
$ ./hello_no_got
Hello, world!
```

I have also tested it on my ~3k LOC app, and it seems to work alright.

P.S. I am not an expert in assembly, so some of the above might be inaccurate.

Comment: Has there ever been a proper fix to this?

Comment: This solution is not sufficient, if you compile a shell code for example you put all the sections into one .text section. You cannot make this reallocations manually if done this way. Hope someone on the llvm/rust community notice this and will remove the GOT on a fully static binaries

Comment: I was under the impression that ASLR requires poisition independent code, and so a GOT. And that in x64 even static binaries were subject to ASLR.

Comment: I've not found a proper fix, yet. I'm building a system with no standard libraries (no crt0.o), and it's coming up with an essential-but-wrong got.

Comment: It appears (using aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-8 and -10) when taking the address of a function from a different source file.

It did not happen with my home-compiled aarch64-none-elf-gcc 8.4.0.

aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-10 part1.c part2.c -o static.elf -static -nostdlib -O4 && aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -x static.elf

part1.c contains _start, which simply returns the address of a function in part2.c.

Comment: A difference is that the ones that produce the GOT seem to default to -fPIC (possibly because of the -linux-, not -none- part).

Comment: In my case, chosing -fno-PIC on the command line stops the GOT from being generated. (You can check if a given gcc has -fPIC by default by using -mcmodel=large, which is apparently incompatible with -fPIC.)

Comment: One final comment; I just read that Rust uses LLVM as its backend, so my gcc comments are out of place. I'll leave them there in case someone might find them useful.